# CSS: Custom Toggle switch

Tags: css, checkbox, toggle

I want to build a custom toggle switch, which has a Google maps like pin instead of a circle.

Therefore I did the following:

HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>

<h2>Toggle Switch</h2>

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="slider"></span>
</label>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 40px;
}

.switch input { 
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 50% 50% 50%;
  border: 3px solid black;
  transform: rotate(225deg);
  margin-top: 20px;
}



input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}
```

It is nearly what I was trying to do. But I need the pin to be rotated until the 'arrowhead' points to the bottom again. So a full rotation.

Is that somehow possible?

You can find my code here:
https://codepen.io/lsgit/pen/GRRbrQq

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure if this is what you want to achieve, but here is a hard coded example:
 Inside the `input:checked + .slider:before` , I changed the transformation to 
 `transform: rotate(45deg) translateX(23px) translateY(-14px);`

Answer (score 0):

Update these styles

```
.slider:before {
  transform: translate(0px) rotate(-132deg);
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  transform: translate(25px) rotate(223deg);
}
```

use `-web-kits` and `-ms` yourself Thanks